# Distance between two locations - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, distance

I'm trying to find the location between two points using google maps. Here is the code that I'm working with:

```
function initialize() {
          var myOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.8813329,-103.6975488),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

           var impactCoordinates = [
              new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
              new google.maps.LatLng(34.1633766,-81.6487862),
                             ];
            var ImpactPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: impactCoordinates,
              strokeColor: "#FF0000",
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2
            });

            ImpactPath.setMap(map);

            var loc1 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897);
            var loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(34.1633766,-81.6487862);

            alert(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(loc1, loc2));
        }
```

This is the error I get from the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'spherical' of undefined

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you haven't done so, explicitly add the geometry library in your `<script>` tag
`src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false">`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: It's also necessary to use the URL above; that is, `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&?libraries=geometry` will not work.

Comment: @Arthur that's because you forgot to remove the question mark. `&?libraries=geometry` should be `&libraries=geometry`

Comment: Thank you. If you have Google maps working, then you just add the name=value pair to the query string: "&libraries=geometry". Debugger says sensor=false is not needed. Now to figure out what that number is that comes back (I need miles). Crow flies is ok.